# How to join two collections in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have two Schema defined as below:

```
var WorksnapsTimeEntry = BaseSchema.extend({
 student: {
     type: Schema.ObjectId,
     ref: 'Student'
 },
 timeEntries: {
     type: Object
 }
 });

var StudentSchema = BaseSchema.extend({
firstName: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    default: ''
    // validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, 'Please fill in your first name']
},
lastName: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    default: ''
    // validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, 'Please fill in your last name']
},
displayName: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
},
municipality: {
    type: String
    }
});
```

And I would like to loop thru each student and show it's time entries. So far I have this code which is obviously not right as I still dont know how do I join WorksnapTimeEntry schema table.

```
Student.find({ status: 'student' })
        .populate('student')
        .exec(function (err, students) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(400).send({
                    message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
                });
            }
            _.forEach(students, function (student) {
               // show student with his time entries....
            });
            res.json(students);
        });
```

Any one knows how do I achieve such thing?

Comment: You are doing it the wrong way around. You want to `.populate()` the "student" path  from the `WorksnapTimeEntry` as a source. If you are expecting it the other way around, then you either include the references as an "array" in each `Student` or you query and combine manually, looking up the "student" field in the `WorksnapTimeEntry`. The `.populate()` method can only work with references "already stored" in the object.

Comment: @BlakesSeven the thing that I am doing this way is that I want to first display all students on table and then show time entries for each of them, I cant show timeEntries as they are milions on table... I was trying something like this adding to the student Schema but still does not seem working:   timeEntries: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'WorksnapsTimeEntry' }],

And then .populate('student') will be like .populate('timeEntries'), could u tell me why this is not working?

Comment: No it would be `WorksnapsTimeEntry.find().populate("students").exec({..})` since `"students"` is a "path" in that model, and a "path" is what you supply as an argument to `.populate()`. If you want a different format then you would need to re-work the results. Or as I already said, you would need to create the references to each `WorksnapTimeEntry` "inside" the `Student` model documents instead. That is how `.populate()` works. Your current thinking is in reverse.

Comment: @BlakesSeven, if I do WorksnapsTimeEntry.find().populate("students").exec({..}) then it will show me milions of students for each time entry which I dont want that.  Isn't there any method that I can use Student.find and then just join all time entries which belongs to that student, by adding to the Student Model the WorksnapTimeEntry array ref or smth?

Comment: @BlakesSeven I actually want this:  Or as I already said, you would need to create the references to each WorksnapTimeEntry "inside" the Student model documents instead.

Comment: Are you actually reading anything I said? It doesn't seem like it. Go back and read it all again and learn something. Everything you are doing is around the wrong way.

Comment: OK, let me ask you this, how do I do it on the right way? Could you maybe re-design the schema or write the query for showing a student with all its time entries? I am kinda confused with this, and I know I should have something on the Student model which will reference WorksnapTimeEntry so that I can grab directly from the Student Model, but I just dont know how do I do that thing...

Comment: More than just a little baffled by what you think you are trying to do here. There is for example no `"status"` field in either schema. Should it be present on `Student`? If then is all you actually want to do is get the "related" `WorksnapsTimeEntry`items for the matched `Student` entries by some other condition?

Comment: @BlakesSeven, sorry the Student Schema was too long, so I didnt show it all, but yes status is inside Student... and yes that's what I actually want to do....

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't want `.populate()` here but instead you want two queries, where the first matches the `Student` objects to get the `_id` values, and the second will use [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) to match the respective `WorksnapsTimeEntry` items for those "students".

Using [`async.waterfall`](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall) just to avoid some indentation creep:

```
async.waterfall(
    [
        function(callback) {
          Student.find({ "status": "student" },{ "_id": 1 },callback);
        },
        function(students,callback) {
            WorksnapsTimeEntry.find({
                "student": { "$in": students.map(function(el) {
                    return el._id
                })
            },callback);
        }
    ],
    function(err,results) {
       if (err) {
          // do something
       } else {
          // results are the matching entries
       }
    }
)
```

If you really must, then you can `.populate("student")` on the second query to get populated items from the other table.

The reverse case is to query on `WorksnapsTimeEntry` and return "everything", then filter out any `null` results from `.populate()` with a "match" query option:

```
WorksnapsTimeEntry.find().populate({
    "path": "student",
    "match": { "status": "student" }
}).exec(function(err,entries) {
   // Now client side filter un-matched results
   entries = entries.filter(function(entry) {
       return entry.student != null;
   });
   // Anything not populated by the query condition is now removed
});
```

So that is not a desirable action, since the "database" is not filtering what is likely the bulk of results.

Unless you have a good reason not to do so, then you probably "should" be "embedding" the data instead. That way the properties like `"status`" are already available on the collection and additional queries are not required.

If you are using a NoSQL solution like MongoDB you should be embracing it's concepts, rather than sticking to relational design principles. If you are consistently modelling relationally, then you might as well use a relational database, since you won't be getting any benefit from the solution that has other ways to handle that.

Comment: i am getting error  },callback); here like expected : so how can i fix it?

Answer (score 38):

As of version 3.2, you can use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup) in aggregation pipeline to perform left outer join.

```
Student.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        from: "worksnapsTimeEntries", // collection name in db
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "student",
        as: "worksnapsTimeEntries"
    }
}]).exec(function(err, students) {
    // students contain WorksnapsTimeEntries
});
```

Comment: is the local field is pointing the current collection and foreign field is pointing the another collection?

Answer (score 5):

It is late but will help many developers.
Verified with

> "mongodb": "^3.6.2",
> "mongoose": "^5.10.8",

Join two collections in mongoose

```
ProductModel.find({} , (err,records)=>{
    if(records)
        //reurn records
    else
        // throw new Error('xyz')

})
.populate('category','name') //select only category name joined collection
//.populate('category') // Select all detail
.skip(0).limit(20)
//.sort(createdAt : '-1')
.exec()
```

ProductModel Schema

```
const CustomSchema = new Schema({
    category:{
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Category'
    },
     ...
}, {timestamps:true}, {collection: 'products'});
module.exports = model('Product',CustomSchema)
```

Category model schema

```
const CustomSchema = new Schema({
 
    name:   { type: String, required:true },
    ...
}, {collection: 'categories'});
module.exports = model('Category',CustomSchema)
```