# what is the Mongoose find query using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

This is my players model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),Schema = mongoose.Schema;  
var playerSchema = Schema({  
  name: String,
  password: String,
  country: String
});
mongoose.model('players', playerSchema);
```

This is my countries model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),Schema = mongoose.Schema;  
var countrySchema = Schema({  
  name: String,
  isActive: Boolean
});
mongoose.model('countries', countrySchema);
```

And this is app.js

```
mongoose.model('players').find({}, function (err, players) {
            console.log(players);
              if (err) {
                  return console.error(err);
              } else {
                  res.format({
                      html: function(){
                        res.render('players/index', {
                              title: 'Players List',
                              "players" : players
                          });
                    },
                    json: function(){
                        res.json(players);
                    }
                });
              }
        });
```

In players model I have countryId and in countries model I have corresponding countryName. Now I want to find players with country name with same find() query.

Comment: Look at this question you should find your happiness : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36805784/how-to-join-two-collections-in-mongoose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use mongoose **populate** method

refer this link: [mongoose populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

in your example, it something like this:

```
mongoose.model('players').find().populate('country').exec(function(err,players){

});
```

this will give you result of both countryID and Name

Comment: Only countryId field is showing but the result of countryId is null.What do I do ?

Comment: read article that i have mention. you have to give ref field which you want to populate while creating schema

Answer (score 0):

mongodb is nosql-database, not a relational database like mysql/postgre. So modelling your data is not like relationaldatabses where you can make one query that joins two tables (in mongodb, "tables" are called collections).

In MongoDB and your current Schema you will first need to find the countryId of the country you want. And then find the players that have that country.

Alternatives;

1. you can store the countryName directly on the player collection
2. you can store the playerId's in an array within the the country collection

further more, in your playerSchema, `country` should be a `ObjectId`, not a `String`.