# How can i Join in mongodb and covert this SQL code to mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

```sql
select*
from AvailableProperty as a JOIN Branch as b 
where a.branchId=b._id
```

I tried this but it's not working properly.

```js
 let data = await AvailableProperty.find({ Type_property: "Sell" })
    .populate({
      path: "branchId",
      match: { _id: req.user.id},
      select: "name _id adressNumber1 adressNumber2 status",
    })
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to join two collections in mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36805784/how-to-join-two-collections-in-mongoose)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the reference in your `Schema`. If you add the reference information from what you are passing to the populate function in the Schema and then populate is suspect it would work!

For reference: `https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html`

Comment: branchId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Branch",
    }, i have reference field in branch schema but its not match in populate func

Comment: the field should be called `branch: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Objectid, ref: "Branch" }` and then you can populate by using `.populate('branch')`

Comment: is there any difference between branchId and branch ?

Comment: but only i wanna get all available properties in all branch s with mongoose query without any javascript code like for and other loops for better performance

Comment: I do not know exactly what you mean but if you do not intend to call populate every time you can use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-autopopulate

Comment: No see i have properties in branch's it mean i have multiple properties in multiple branch with one user , i wanna write a query to get every properties in every branch's in one company!, did you got ?

Comment: ah i see where do you define this relationship do you refer to the `branch` in the `user` object or to the `user` in the `branch` object?

Comment: yeah but in which way or both ways?

Comment: if you have declared the branch in user as follows `branches: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.objectid, ref: "Branch" }]` here if you `.populate('branches')` you should get a list of branches from your `Schema`

Comment: in each branch schema  i have userid and in property's schema i have brabchid , in my query i wanna get every properties that have branchid of this user

Comment: then I think what you need is my above answer, this is the way I got a `user` class with multiple `documents` coupled to it and with one simple `populate` get the `user` and with the user on its prop a list of the `documents` so a one to many relationship JOIN with one call

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to use populate() to get the same result as the SQL query you provided in your question:

```
const query = AvailableProperty.find().populate('branchId'); 

// Execute the query and populate the results 
query.exec((err, properties) => {
  if (err) {
    // handle error
  } 
  else {
    // you can access joined documents here 
  } 
});
```

Notice that branchId references the _id field in the Branch model.